# DART: how can i reorder randomly characters in a string?

Tags: dart, random, shuffle

how can i change randomly the character orders in a string?

example, Input: hello - Output: elolh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`List.shuffle`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.1/dart-core/List/shuffle.html) :

```dart
var text = 'HELLO';

// First turn you text into a List :
List list = text.split('');

// Shuffle the list :
list.shuffle();

// Then turn back the list into a String
String shuffled = list.join();

print(shuffled); // LLHOE
```

One-liner :

```dart
String shuffled = ('HELLO'.split('')..shuffle()).join();
```

Extension method :

```dart
void main() {
  var text = 'HELLO';
  var shuffled = text.shuffled();
  print(shuffled); // OLEHL
}


extension on String {
  String shuffled() =>
    (this.split('')..shuffle()).join();
}
```